# How do I open my editor while I am selecting a file in project explorer?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

When i am selecting a file in the project explorer, it should allow me to open my editor instead it shows text editor.How can we handle this programmatically in eclipse plugin development ?

regards
Mathan

Comment: Does it only open in the Text Editor, or is your editor also available from the file's Open With context menu?

Answer (score 1):

**Window - Preferences - General - Editors - File Associations**

Their you can select which editor is open, for the different file endings.

When you want to do this with a self implemented editor you have to implement the extension poin for editors

**org.eclipse.ui.editors**

The field "***extensions***" defines which file ending is associated to the editor

Answer (score 1):

There is also possibility to register your own content type of file. It can be registered as a sub-type of existing content type i.e. XML. To do that you should add an extension point of `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes`

Sample extension point:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type
        base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
        default-charset="UTF-8"
        describer="com.example.MyContentDescriber"
        file-extensions="xml"
        id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml.exampleContentType"
        name="exampleContentType"
        priority="normal">
  </content-type>
```

As you can see new content type is extending an xml content type. The next step is to implement content describer, which looks into the file and determines if it is of your type. There are two interfaces you can implement to do the job: `IContentDescriber` or `ITextContentDescriber`. Path to your implementation of describer must be specified in content type as it is shown in the snippet.

Then your editor can be declared as the one, who will be handling your kind of content types.

```
<editor class="com.example.MyEditor"
        default="true"
        icon="res/icons/dialog.png"
        id="[some_id]"
        name="Dialog editor">
     <contentTypeBinding
           contentTypeId="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml.exampleContentType">
     </contentTypeBinding>
  </editor>
```

Important things:

- files that have been already opened in eclipse might 'remember' in which editor they were last opened and this one will be chosen,
- your describer might be used a lot so you should consider performance issues while implementing it

More in the topic:
[ECLIPSE: Contributing content types](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_content_contributing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Any plugin that contributes an editor to the workbench can associate an extension the editor understands in their plugin.xml.

> The extensions attribute describes the file types that the editor understands.  (You could also specify filenames if you need to be more specific.)

I believe this is enough to make your editor open when you click a file of your extension. (at least be preferred the first time you open the file. i.e. eclipse will prefer the last used editor for that file that session).

[More info.](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_editors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Using the file extension method is preferred because that's easy.  However if you can't do that, then the only alternative I know of is to provide an action provider in the Common Navigator configuration.

You will need to subclass CommonActionProvider and in the fillContextMenu() method you can look at the resource and then decide to have your own Open action (for your editor) or add the standard Open action.